# Laws affecting local government in New York State

Tags: new-york-state

I've looked online for the answer to this, but I keep coming up with contradictory or ambiguous information.

In the Consolidated Laws enacted by the New York State Legislature which apply to local governments (i.e. Counties, Cities, Towns or Villages), there are subject matter divisions, such as Education Law, Retirement and Social Security Law, and Highway Law.

### Question

> Does General City Law, despite its name, also apply to a Town,
>                  County or Village in New York State?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Towns, counties and villages are governed by the Town Law, the County Law, and the Village Law, respectively:

- http://codes.lp.findlaw.com/nycode/TWN
- http://codes.lp.findlaw.com/nycode/VIL
- http://codes.lp.findlaw.com/nycode/CNT

There are some exceptions to this; notably, the five counties that compose New York City are generally excluded from the County Law.